# Average values in same month python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Date     Water   Milk
2020-01-25    21      58
2020-01-21    25      54 
2020-01-14    64      22
2020-02-25    54      58
2020-02-16    21      94
2020-03-28    45      95
2020-03-23    64      95
```

I want to take the average of the Water and Milk values that have the same month and store the averages in a new dataframe so that it looks like:

```
Date     Water      Milk
 1      36.6667   44.6667
 2       37.5       76
 3       54.5       95
```

Where the date column only outputs the month, and the water and milk values are averaged for those months. Is this possible using the python pandas library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) with aggregate `mean`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
cols = df.columns.difference(['Date']) 
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(float)
#alternative
#df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

df1 = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month).mean().reset_index()
print (df1)
   Date      Water       Milk
0     1  36.666667  44.666667
1     2  37.500000  76.000000
2     3  54.500000  95.000000
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "No numeric types to aggregate." Any ideas how to fix this? I think it may stem from how I'm storing my dates in the initial dataframe